# What's the second minimum value that a decimal can represent?

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

What's the *second minimum* value that a `decimal` can represent? That is the value which is larger than `Decimal.MinValue` and smaller than any other values that a `decimal` can represent. How can I obtain this value in C#? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second-minimum value is `Decimal.MinValue + 1`.

This can be inferred from the documentation for `decimal`:

> A decimal number is a floating-point value that consists of a sign, a
>   numeric value where each digit in the value ranges from 0 to 9, and a
>   scaling factor that indicates the position of a floating decimal point
>   that separates the integral and fractional parts of the numeric value.
>
> The binary representation of a Decimal value consists of a 1-bit sign,
>   a 96-bit integer number, and a scaling factor used to divide the
>   96-bit integer and specify what portion of it is a decimal fraction.
>   The scaling factor is implicitly the number 10, raised to an exponent
>   ranging from 0 to 28. Therefore, the binary representation of a
>   Decimal value is of the form, ((-2^96 to 2^96) / 10^(0 to 28)), where
>   -2^96-1 is equal to MinValue, and 2^96-1 is equal to MaxValue.

From the above we can infer that on the extreme edges of the legal value range, the scaling factor is `1` (10 to the power 0) and therefore that's the smallest quantum when a decimal value is modified.

**[Live proof](http://ideone.com/L5vv4)**.

Answer (score 6):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx), a decimal is represented like `((-2^96 to 2^96) / 10^(0 to 28))`, where `-2^96-1` is equal to `MinValue`, and `2^96-1` is equal to `MaxValue`, so the smallest difference between two decimals is `1/10^28`.
That difference is only possible between small decimals though. Generally, as a decimal becomes larger (no matter the sign), you lose decimal points, until there are none left.

UPDATE: As also pointed out in the comments, you can't actually change `decimal.MinValue` by adding the smallest decimal value (as above). Decimal has 1 bit for the sign, 96 bit for a number and a scaling factor (10^x) by which the number is divided.

In order to get to such a large negative number, the exponent portion of the scaling factor must be set to `0` (-> 10^0 == 1), because setting it to anything higher would cause the number to be divided by that and thus it would get smaller.

That means, for such a number, the smallest difference would be `1/10^0`, or `1`.

So you are looking for this:

```
decimal.MinValue + 1m;
```

Comment: +1, I *think* this is what the OP is after. Possibly the answer would be `Decimal.MinValue + 0.000...1`.

Comment: @Botz3000, @George: But `(Decimal.MinValue + 0.000...1) == Decimal.MinValue`.

Comment: -1: This is incorrect. The scaling factor represents the portion of the 96 bits that is a decimal fraction. You can trivially confirm this by checking what `Decimal.MinValue + 0.000001m` is.

Comment: @LukeH: Surely there is some number that when added to `Decimal.MinValue` such that `Decimal.MinValue + x > Decimal.MinValue` where `x < 1`.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: "Surely" why? Any hard facts?

Comment: @Jon, see my comment on the other answer. I'm guessing that my understanding of decimal is wrong.

Comment: @George: Well, you could set `x` to `0.49999999999999999999999999995` in your source code if you like, but `Decimal.MinValue + x` would still be `-79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,334`.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Please remove your upvote too, as this answer is factually wrong.

Comment: @Jon: I tried to earlier, but no edit so couldn't. Have now removed.

Comment: @Jon Got it wrong. I edited my answer and added some explanation of the reason.

Comment: @Botz3000: Downvote removed, but please edit further because the very first line of the current version is still wrong.

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.minvalue.aspx

```
Decimal.MinValue + 1
```

So: -79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,334.

Comment: I think you mean _negative_ 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,334

Comment: Since it's decimal why add 1.0, why not 0.00000....1 (maybe what asker is asking)

Comment: @George: Because the `Decimal` type can't represent any intermediate values between `-79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335` and `-79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,334`. The smallest discrete step is 1.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now, as i thought the point of decimal (as opposed to float etc.) is that the difference in values it can represent is fixed.